# netty channel close failed in userEventTriggered invoke

Tags: netty, heartbeat

netty 4.1.6:
the server triggers an IdleStateEvent every 30 seconds but never call the channelInactive method. Last for a long time.

and the server side too many CLOSE_WAIT

LAST_ACK 10
CLOSE_WAIT 3708
ESTABLISHED 7

```
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        IdleStateEvent event = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
        if (event.state().equals(IdleState.READER_IDLE)) {//只处理读操作
            logger.debug("time out close channel: {}", ctx.channel().id().asLongText());
            ctx.channel().close();
        }

    } else {
        super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
    }

}
```

[the logs of same channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KOIp.png)

Comment: This version is very old... please upgrade to 4.1.29.Final and check if the problem still exists.

Comment: upgrade 4.1.29 , and the problem still exists

Comment: Please share your code